# Change Jenkins text "build" to "Linux Build" or "Mac Build"

Tags: github, jenkins

Can we be more precise of target build?

I would like to know if we can customize a build type text of Jenkins. Most of the project have a table format instead[image]

[image]

*.svg source*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="90" height="20">
  <linearGradient id="a" x2="0" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bbb" stop-opacity=".1"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-opacity=".1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <rect rx="3" width="90" height="20" fill="#555"/>
  <rect rx="3" x="37" width="53" height="20" fill="#4c1"/>
  <path fill="#4c1" d="M37 0h4v20h-4z"/>
  <rect rx="3" width="90" height="20" fill="url(#a)"/>
  <g fill="#fff" text-anchor="middle" font-family="DejaVu Sans,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif" font-size="11">
    <text x="19.5" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">build</text>
    <text x="19.5" y="14">build</text>
    <text x="62.5" y="15" fill="#010101" fill-opacity=".3">passing</text>
    <text x="62.5" y="14">passing</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```